# Android Showing Activity on Android Phone LockScreen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, lockscreen, foreground-service

I am trying to show a activity as USER open his phone

I did these

1.Foreground Service with a Broad Cast Receiver to show a activity on LockScreen

```java
public class OverlayService extends Service {
    NotificationManager manager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else {
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
            Toast.makeText(this, "  Service Is Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground() {

        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = ".....";
        String channelName = "Foreground Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        chan.setShowBadge(false);
        manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("text_my")
                .setContentText("my_text")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_EVENT)
                .build();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            startForeground(2, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_DATA_SYNC);
        }
        startForeground(2, notification);
        Toast.makeText(this, " ...Service Is Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        registerOverlayReceiver();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterOverlayReceiver();
    }

    private void registerOverlayReceiver() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_DEBUG);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_UNLOCKED);
        }
        registerReceiver(overlayReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void unregisterOverlayReceiver() {
        unregisterReceiver(overlayReceiver);
    }

    private static final String ACTION_DEBUG = "....text";

    private final BroadcastReceiver overlayReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            assert action != null;
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                showOverlayActivity(context);
            } else if (action.equals(ACTION_DEBUG)) {
                showOverlayActivity(context);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_UNLOCKED)) {
                showOverlayActivity(context);
            }
        }

    };

    private void showOverlayActivity(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, com.rad.mls.OverlayActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

2. In  OverlayActivity to show on LockScreen

```java
final Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

3. Permission in Android Manifest

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

4. Activity in Manifest

```xml
<activity
            android:name=".OverlayActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Lockscreen" />
```

5. The way I start Foreground Service

```java
Intent i = new Intent(this, OverlayService.class);
        i.setAction("C.ACTION_START_SERVICE");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) startForegroundService(i);
        else
            startService(i);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Give app permission to DISPLAY(DRAW) OVER TOP OF OTHER APPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent;
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
                    } else {
                        intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    }
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
```

Also I've asked user that if they are on MIUI to go to permissions and allow app to show on lockscreen but still

> MAIN PROBLEM : Although it works on most devices but still in many
> devices activity didn't show over Pattern/Password lock also in many
> devices the service get automatically killed after some time and it
> stops showing activity

---

> Is there a proper way you can show a layout with event listeners on lockscreen
> Or what's the ways which is most near to perfect in acheiving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually on 8+ you need some other codes and the deprecated flags won't work

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1){
    setShowWhenLocked(true)
    setTurnScreenOn(true)
}

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
    (getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as? KeyguardManager)?.requesDismissKeyguard()
}
```

Also don't forget a backdoor for being able to start activities in Android 10+ (like system alert window permission)
Also MIUI has a lot of shitty items added to android and the most comprehensive code I've found is inside QuickLyric's source code

https://github.com/QuickLyric/QuickLyric/blob/master/QuickLyric/src/main/java/com/geecko/QuickLyric/utils/PermissionsChecker.java

Comment: Thank You Bro ,  that Permission Checker really helps

Comment: You're welcome, the best mind blowing part is that `displayMIUIPopupPermission` he has implemented 3 different intents (and I'm not sure if that covers 100% of MIUI devices)

Comment: it should , cause the code in the last  catch block is same for all android so even if it's not specially for MIUI  it will work like default

Comment: Yeah but miui has 4 options like showing floating widget while foreground/background and display over lockscreen while foreground/backgrounr and probably there might be another version of miui which is not inside his code and the default intent will be launched instead, and as a result on that particular MIUI we would launch default, only acquiring standard SAW which is equal to SAW while im foreground is xiaomi